# MySQL - Select all from table and select related rows from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**SCENARIO:** 
I need to select 20 users with all their information and also select their teacher profile with all the languages they teach. I am trying to do this but it seems that mysql only return an array of value with no nested array of values, is there any way to do it?

**TABLES:**

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                  users                   |
+------------------------------------------+
|  id  |  firstname  |        email        |
+------------------------------------------+
|  18  |     Tom     |   jerry@email.com   |
+------------------------------------------+
|  30  |    Jerry    |   tom@email.com     |
+------------------------------------------+
|  25  |    Butch    |   butch@email.com   |
+------------------------------------------+

+------------------------------------+
|               teachers             |
+------------------------------------+
|  id  |  user_id  |  trial_lessons  |
+------------------------------------+
|  10  |    18     |       yes       |
+------------------------------------+
|  26  |    30     |       no        |
+------------------------------------+
|  28  |    25     |       no        |
+------------------------------------+

+------------------------------------------+
|            teacher_languages             |
+------------------------------------------+
|  id  |  teacher_id  |  language_text_id  |
+------------------------------------------+
|  16  |      10      |         6          |
+------------------------------------------+
|  40  |      10      |         8          |
+------------------------------------------+
|  16  |      28      |         6          |
+------------------------------------------+
|  16  |      28      |        10          |
+------------------------------------------+
|  16  |      26      |         6          |
+------------------------------------------+

+-------------------+
|     languages     |
+-------------------+
|  id  |  language  |
+-------------------+
|   6  |   English  |
+-------------------+
|   8  |   French   |
+-------------------+
|  10  |   Spanish  |
+-------------------+
```

**MY CODE SO FAR**

```
SELECT 
    users.*,        
    nationality.country AS country_of_nationality,
    residence.country AS country_of_residence,
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    text_countries AS nationality
ON
    users.nationality = nationality.iso_code_2
AND
    nationality.language_id = ?
LEFT JOIN
    text_countries AS residence
ON
    users.residence_country = residence.iso_code_2
AND
    residence.language_id = ?
ORDER BY 
    users.created_at 
DESC LIMIT 
        20
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
[0] => 
    [user_id]    => 18
    [firstname]  => 'Tom'
    [teacher_id] => 10
    [languages]  =>
                 [language] => 'English'
                 [language] => 'French'
[1] => 
    [user_id]    => 30
    [firstname]  => 'Jerry'
    [teacher_id] => 26
    [languages]  =>
                 [language] => 'English'
[2] => 
    [user_id]    => 25
    [firstname]  => 'Butch'
    [teacher_id] => 28
    [languages]  =>
                 [language] => 'English'
                 [language] => 'Spanish'
```

Comment: Show us your code so far, try it out yourself before asking for help.

Comment: MySQL doesn't return multi dimensional records. Every record is 1-D. Most relational dbs do that. You could maybe use `GROUP_CONCAT` to collect multiple values into 1 column though, depending on how you need the languages data.

Comment: I already did, the code I have so far is very long because it counts from multiple tables and it won't let me post the question if most of it is code. Cheers!

Comment: See the JOIN operation on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't return multi dimensional records. Every record is 1-D. Most relational dbs do that.

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to collect multiple values into 1 column though, depending on how you need the languages data:

```
SELECT stuff, GROUP_CONCAT(l.language) AS languages
FROM users u
JOIN teachers t ON ....
JOIN teacher_languages tl ON ....
JOIN languages l ON ....
GROUP BY u.id
```

I'm assuming you know (and have?) the `JOIN`s... You need an extra JOIN (multiple) to `teacher_languages` and then another JOIN (single) to `languages` and then you collect the multiple language records into 1 value using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it works nicely the problem now is that it return a single value with the info of one user and concats all the available languages into it.

Comment: I was missing the `GROUP BY u.id` it got me confused the way you wrote it in your code, why you wrote it that way?

Comment: I don't know =) I guess I could've just said `GROUP BY u.id`... I changed the answer. Sorry, not very clear. Does it work now?